# Get onchange event if I don't write in a input text

Tags: javascript

I have a table and when I click in a row the data of this row is copy to some input text. I have an empty select combobox and this will fill with one thing or another depend the content of the input. I'm ussing the event onchange for do this but it doesn't work because I'm not writing in the input. I put here the relevant code.

```
<td><input type="text" id="club" value="" onchange="load()"/></td>
function load()
{
var club=document.getElementById("club").value;
alert(club);
}
```

Comment: Why not call `load()` from the click handler of the row? Notice, that `window.load` is a native DOM method, you should not override it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty and straight forward way of doing this is to use bindings as in some reactive libraries like knockoutjs. 
A quick hack is to call your load function in the click handler for a row after all your processing. ( copying text n all).

Comment: That's work. I call the function in the handler of the click row function. Thanks.

Comment: good one. i like it. arguments are always good. take some time and read http://vanilla-js.com/. n btw knockout is not a framework. it is a pattern(valid). not like jquery which only misleads people from real javascript. Just read it. nothing more.

Comment: Actually I've read that article before, and sometimes even provided a link to it. Usually guys asking questions like this are more or less newbies with JS, and they should stay as far away as possible from all libraries until they have got an idea of how JS and DOM works. Unfortenately recommendators are everywhere pushing some library to a newbie, [like here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48195/202792)...

Comment: read about knockout js. it is not something like jquery which is a framework. jquery is like building a poor IDE using an exising better IDE. knockout is a pattern. What he is trying to achieve belongs to that pattern. It is a concept. and knockout is pure javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the script in question has to be withing  tags if you're defining it inline with html (which I don't recommend)

secondly, you'll need to prepend your function call with javascript: e.g.

onchange="javascript:load()"

I would recommend looking into event listeners or jquery instead, however.

Comment: `javascript:` pseudo-protocol hasn't been used for years in online event handlers, it's badly deprecated.

Comment: jquery? scary.. jquery is some useless thing build over javascript. visit http://vanilla-js.com/ and go throught it. It is one of the worse things that ever happened to javascript which by itself is doomed. move on gentlemen.

Comment: Arun, your opinion is your own. The fact is jQuery is used in millions of production environments worldwide.

Comment: Thats what i said. It is not my own opinion. Understand the deficiencis and performance issues before using some library. Jquery is not worth it. Just visit the page and read it. understand it.

Comment: @ArunAravind Intrestingly you recommended another library in your answer ; ).

Comment: Im not against libraries. I just said "jquery". knockout is not just another library. It is an entirely different concept (MVVM).

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("club").onchange();
```

Should do the trick. You can fire these events manually!

Comment: This way you can trigger just very few events (like `focus`, `blur` and `click`). Also there should not be `on` in front of event's name, when using an event method. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) doesn't even mention these methods...

Comment: @teemu My experiment tells me otherwise (http://jsfiddle.net/Zy6Z9/) and there is certainly more than "very few" events that can be triggered this way. `onclick` for example can also be fired with just `click()`, though.